# How to find a particular string within a Source code(Xpath) and extract the proceeding text?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

From the following source code :

```
<html>
...
<div>.......</div>
<script bounce ="bla">....</script>
<div>.......</div>
.
.
n
.
<script bounce="foo">....],[null,"bla bla"]........</script>
.
.
.
</html>
```

I want to extract the (bla bla) which is definetely coming after (,[null,") till the point ("])
The reason why I cannot go via script name id and div is because they are dynamic for every page I'm scraping via scrapy. Thus the code must look for (,[null,") and extract the proceeding text.

Comment: Can't you use regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to find script node and get its text with XPath:

```
node = html.select('//script[contains(., "[null,")]/text()').extract()
```

and then extract required substring:

```
node.split("[null,")[-1].split("]")[0]
```

Comment: I think this will do the work... Will check and mark it as the answer.. Thanks BTW

Comment: just want to clarify one thing that will there be a need to use  escape sequence for " , as if the source code is having -- `.....already extracted line end here"]
,[null,"......"]'
So can I use ('//script[contains(.,'here"],[null,"')]') ?

Comment: If I correctly understand you might need `("""//script[contains(.,'here"],[null,"')]""")` to avoid quotes escaping

Comment: you got me right but just a last thing. if the source  ...end here"]
,[null,"Start..."] has a line break between here"] and ,[null then how do I add that between the here"] and ,[null

Comment: Hmm... Do you mean HTML looks like `<script>.end here"]<br>,[null,"Start..."]</script>`?

Comment: There is no <br> tag but the ,[null starts in a new line. The shell show it as \n but while putting here"]\n,[null," in [contains] returns blank.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing exact HTML. You can try `("""//script[contains(.,'here"]') and contains(. ,'[null,"')]""")`, but it's more like an workaround

Comment: It worked with [contains(.,'!"]\n,[null,"')] . Thanks a lot for your time..... You saved me hours.... Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

```
value = response.xpath('//script[@bounce="foo"]/text()').re_first( r',\s*\[\s*null,\s*"([^"]+)' )
```

But it looks like you're trying to parse some kind of JSON string inside Javascript so it's better to parse whole JSON and next navigate to your string:

```
json_string = response.xpath('//script[@bounce="foo"]/text()').extract_first()
data = json.loads(json_string)

value = data[someindex][anotherindex][etc]
```